# Serialization of any solidity type

Tags: go-ethereum, data-types

My initial aim was to return structure from the function.

After web search I ended up with serialization of data structure into bytes array.

Now I try to figure out how each type is represented in bytes and what is the dependency to properly convert it into `bytes` and backwards.

`uint`
`address`
`bytes32`

Can you provide docs which explains the dependency between data type and its representation in bytes?

[Conversion uint to bytes](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11246/convert-struct-to-bytes-in-solidity)
[Conversion uint256 bytes](https://gitter.im/ethereum/solidity?at=56b8a608939ffd5d15f66e99)

Comment: Solidity supports returning multiple values. Just return the values from the struct.

Comment: I operate with array of structs. Simply enumeration of all values in return statement would not be a good solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Seriality](https://github.com/pouladzade/Seriality) library. [Seriality](https://github.com/pouladzade/Seriality) is a library for serializing and de-serializing all the Solidity types in a very efficient way which mostly written in solidity-assembly

1- By means of Seriality you can easily serialize and deserialize your variables, structs, arrays, tuples, ... and pass them through the contracts and libraries.

2- You can decouple your contract from libraries by serializing parameters into a byte array.

3- It also can be used as an alternative for RLP protocol in Solidity.

Here is a sample :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

import "./Seriality.sol";

contract SerialitySample is Seriality {

function sample() public returns(int8 n1, int24 n2, uint32 n3, int128 n4, address n5, address n6) {

    bytes memory buffer = new bytes(64);
    int8    out1 = -12;
    int24   out2 = 838860;
    uint32  out3 = 333333333;
    int128  out4 = -44444444444;
    address out5 = 0x15B7926835A7C2FD6D297E3ADECC5B45F7309F59;
    address out6 = 0x1CB5CF010E407AFC6249627BFD769D82D8DBBF71;

    // Serializing
    uint offset = 64;

    intToBytes(offset, out1, buffer);
    offset -= sizeOfInt(8);

    intToBytes(offset, out2, buffer);
    offset -= sizeOfUint(24);

    uintToBytes(offset, out3, buffer);
    offset -= sizeOfInt(32);

    intToBytes(offset, out4, buffer);
    offset -= sizeOfUint(128);

    addressToBytes(offset, out5, buffer);
    offset -= sizeOfAddress();

    addressToBytes(offset, out6, buffer);

    // Deserializing
    offset = 64; 

    n1 = bytesToInt8(offset, buffer);
    offset -= sizeOfInt(8);

    n2 = bytesToInt24(offset, buffer);
    offset -= sizeOfUint(24);

    n3 = bytesToUint8(offset, buffer);
    offset -= sizeOfInt(32);

    n4 = bytesToInt128(offset, buffer);
    offset -= sizeOfUint(128);

    n5 = bytesToAddress(offset, buffer);
    offset -= sizeOfAddress();

    n6 = bytesToAddress(offset, buffer);
}
```

output buffer:

```
1cb5cf010e407afc6249627bfd769d82d8dbbf7115b7926835a7c2fd6d297e3a

decc5b45f7309f59fffffffffffffffffffffff5a6e798e413de43550cccccf4


"1": "int8:     n1 -12",

"2": "int24:    n2 838860",

"3": "uint32:   n3 85",

"4": "int128:   n4 -44444444444",

"5": "address:  n5 0x15b7926835a7c2fd6d297e3adecc5b45f7309f59",

"6": "address:  n6 0x1cb5cf010e407afc6249627bfd769d82d8dbbf71"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can go through [this](https://hackernoon.com/serializing-string-arrays-in-solidity-db4b6037e520) short article for serialization/deserialization in solidity.